# maven-docker-plugin: how to get container ip address

Tags: maven, docker, fabric8, maven-docker-plugin

I am new to Docker and fabric8's `maven-docker-plugin`. I want to do some integration tests using two containers, one with my webapp deployed and one with database.

**UPDATE:**
I can run both containers using these commands:

```
docker run --name db -p 27017:27017 mongo
docker run --name as -p 8080:8080 --link db mycustom/wildfly /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Ddbhost=172.17.0.2 -Ddbport=27017
```

This the dockerfile I use:

```
FROM fpezzati/wildflyogm
ARG webapp
COPY $webapp /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Now I want to run both containers using the fabric8 `maven-docker-plugin`. At this point I have to figure out about how to express a `run` command that is able to take the two arguments `-Ddbhost=${dbhost} -Ddbport=${dbport}` using the `maven-docker-plugin`, where `${dbhost}` and `${dbport}` should be two maven properties having database container ip address and exposed port.
How can I express a run command as I do in the by-hand example and get my webapp aware about database ip address using the fabric8 `maven-docker-plugin`?

**UPDATE:**
I clean up some mess I did in my pom.xml and in dockerfile. Now I can pass arguments by using environment variables.
The only issue left is I can't get database container's ip address even if it is linked into webapp container's `<run>...</run>` configuration.

Here is my project's [pom](https://github.com/fpezzati/Yomoka/blob/master/YoOffer/pom.xml).
I am using `maven 3.3.9`, `docker 1.12.5` and fabric8's `maven-docker-plugin 0.19.0`.

Comment: use `--name` to name a container and `--link` to link a named external container to a container. If an external container is linked, you can use external container's name as it's ip address.

Comment: @200OK hello! I can run both containers and run tests by docker-cli. I want to do it by maven to run integration tests automatically. I update my question so it should be more clear. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. As you link container `A` to container `B`, Docker add `A` as hostname to `B`'s `etc/hosts` file. So you don't have to figure out container's ip address you can just use its name. The same happens on fabric8 `maven-docker-plugin`, which is a great plugin. You use

```
<links>
  <link>A</link>
</links>
```

to link `A` to `B` and `B` can use `A:27017` to reach service on `A`'s exposed port, so in my `pom` I pass the string `A` by enviroment variable instead of container `A`'s ip address. I push solution to my github repo.